# Image in a div stays fixed when the div is being scrolled

Tags: javascript, css

How to make so that an Image in a div stays fixed when the div is being scrolled?

(http://jsfiddle.net/XwXBB/)

Comment: Why don't you give image style="position: fixed"

Answer (score 1):

```
background: url(http://bbs.prog365.com/uc_server/images/noavatar_middle.gif) no-repeat fixed 0 0;
```

Add in the background colour's hex value as well if it's fixed, e.g. `background: #ccc url(..) ..`